# PHP default time zone

Tags: php, linux, timezone

Recently updated to PHP 7.3.2 (built 02/15/19) and since then all of our date('H:i:s') variables no longer respect the default timezone originally set in the ini.

Linux system clock is correct. We reset the timezone, rebooted the server, same issue. phpinfo() reports the correct timezone (America/Denver)

Changing the timezone in the ini and via a test script both have no effect on the date/time printed. All date/time variables are 5 hours off regardless of what we set.

Any help would be appreciated. I wasn't able to find any information that reflected this scenario.

Comment: [Why does PHP 7.3.2 show the wrong time and ignores timezone?](https://superuser.com/q/1403444/173513) and friends. Also see [PHP Issue 77582,  strftime no longer prints correct timezone](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77582).

Comment: Saw that when I was researching our issue. It seems like the bug was resolved pn 02/08/2019, about a week before I installed PHP 7.3.2 on our server.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling 7.3.2 did not resolve the date issue. Removing 7.3.2 and installing 7.3.4 resolved the issue.